# With $[K: F] = 3, \alpha \in K, \beta \in K \backslash F$, show that there are $a,b,c,d \in F$ such that $\alpha = \frac{a+b\beta}{c+d\beta}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

The original question states:

> Let $K$ be an extension of $F$, $[K:F] = 3$. Show that for every $\alpha \in K, \beta \in K \backslash F$, $\alpha = \frac{a+b\beta}{c+d\beta}$ for some  $a,b,c,d \in F$.

For every such $\beta$, $K = F(\beta)$. So there are $a_0, a_1, a_2$ such that $\alpha = a_0 + a_1 \beta + a_2 \beta^2$. How to continue from here?

Comment: Do you mean $[K:F] = 3$? Or has the notation commuted itself since the days I studied this stuff?

Comment: You've got four free parameters, $a,b,c,d$ (although it's really only $3$, because everything's homogeneous). Try multiplying through by the denominator.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yup, $[K :F]$. My bad.

Comment: Multiplying by the denominator gives some incoherent equality, from which I can't seem to solve it

Comment: Write out that incoherent equality for us, and move everything to one side. The result is a polynomial in $\beta$, a polynomial that's equal to the zero polynomial.

Comment: That was what I thought, but then, since $\beta$ is algebraic of degree 3, it means that even though it is equal to zero, the coefficients aren't necessarily zero, but could be, for example, the coefficients of $\beta$'s minimal polynomial. isn't that the case? Then what does this equality give me?

Comment: But the polynomial that you will obtain here in $\beta$ has degree less than $3$ (the degree of the minimal polynomial), so $\beta$ cannot satisfy a polynomial equation of lesser degree (and coefficients in $F$), unless the coefficients are zero.

Comment: But I got a polynomial of degree 3. Will write it out

Comment: If you can *make* the coefficients be zero, then you're done.

Comment: I can do that, In which case I force $c=d=0$

Comment: Turns out I can not do high school algebra. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: nope, still getting $c=d=0$ no matter what I do. I got to $(a_0c - a) + (a_1c + a_0d - b) \beta + (a_2c + a_1d) \beta^2 + a_2d \beta^3 = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine came with a very elegant solution, which I ended up using.

$[K : F] = 3$ implies that $\{1, \alpha, \beta, \alpha\beta\}$ is linearly dependent. So there are $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 \in F$, at least one of which is not equal to $0$, such that $a_1 + a_2 \alpha + a_3 \beta + a_4 \alpha \beta = 0$. A quick rearrangement gives $\alpha = \frac{-a_1 -a_3 \beta}{a_2+a_4\beta}$.

The case where $a_2+a_4\beta = 0$ can be easily ruled out. Since $F(\beta) = K$, $[F(\beta):F] = 3$, so $a_2 = a_4 = 0$. Using that in the first equation we also get $a_1 + a_3 \beta = 0$ so $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 0$.

Comment: you mean that the case can be ruled out because you assumed that at least one of $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ is not equal to $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Write $\alpha=a_0+a_1\beta+a_2\beta^2$. If $a_2=0$, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, write $\alpha= a_2(a_0'+a_1'\beta+\beta^2)= a_2(a_0'+(\frac{a_1'}{2}+\beta)^2-\frac{a_1'^2}{4})= a_2(a_0''+(a_1''+\beta)^2)$, where $a_0',a_1',a_0'',a_1''$ are obviously defined. (Now I see that I have to assume $char F\neq 2$, I don't see now how to deal with this case.)

Consider $\gamma=a_1''+\beta$. Obviously, $K=F(\gamma)$ and minimal polynomial of $\gamma$ over $F$ is of degree $3$; let it be $X^3+b_2X^2+b_1X+b_0$. So $\gamma^3+b_2\gamma^2+b_1\gamma+b_0=0$, wherefrom $\gamma^2=-\frac{b_1\gamma+b_0}{\gamma+b_2}$. By returning, $\alpha= a_2(a_0''+\gamma^2)= a_2(a_0''-\frac{b_1\gamma+b_0}{\gamma+b_2})= \frac{c_0\gamma+c_1}{\gamma+b_2}$, where again $c_i$'s are obviously defined. Since $\beta=\gamma-a_1''$, $\alpha=\frac{c_0\beta+d_0}{\beta+d_1}$, where $d_i$'s are obviously defined.